# Kotlin Callback unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I'm writing a unit test for my app. I need to test a function that handles the login inside my app. This login handler uses a Callback that notifies when the login is complete. This is my Login Handler

```
class LoginManager {

private var auth: FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth

fun loginWithEmail(
        email: String,
        password: String,
        loginCallback: LoginCallback
) {
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { loginTask ->
        if (loginTask.isSuccessful) {
            auth.currentUser?.let { user ->
                loginCallback.onLoginSuccess(user)
                return@addOnCompleteListener
            }
        }

        loginCallback.onLoginFailure(loginTask.exception)
    }
} }
```

LoginCallback is a simple interface

```
interface LoginCallback {
fun onLoginSuccess(user: FirebaseUser)
fun onLoginFailure(error: Exception?) }
```

I need to test the `loginWithEmail` function. In my test I try this code

```
Handler(getMainLooper()).post {
        var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null
        val loginCallback = object : LoginCallback {
            override fun onLoginSuccess(user: FirebaseUser) {
                firebaseUser = user
            }

            override fun onLoginFailure(error: Exception?) {
                //No action needed
            }

        }

        val loginManager = LoginManager(loginCallback)

        loginManager.loginWithEmail(EXISTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS, CORRECT_PASSWORD)
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        assert(firebaseUser != null)
    }

    shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle()
```

But the callback is never being called. I also try with an ArgumentCaptor

```
Handler(getMainLooper()).post {
        val captor =  ArgumentCaptor.forClass(LoginCallback::class.java)
        val loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.loginWithEmail(EXISTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS, CORRECT_PASSWORD, captor.capture())
    }

    shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle()
```

But with this code, I'm getting this error `java.lang.NullPointerException: captor.capture() must not be null`

Is there a way to test my function?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://medium.com/ruangguru-engineering/tips-on-unit-testing-in-android-with-kotlin-d8d70beff401)?

Comment: The capture() is still returning null

"java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null"

Comment: Well, your code is completely dependent on `auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` - how are you ensuring that completes in your test?

Comment: I think that is my issue, I have no idea of how to ensure that auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword is complete. I tried with a Thread.sleep(20000) but it did not work.